# node_module inclusion in a Typescript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, configuration, gulp

I am relatively new to javascript framework configuration, and am trying to configure the compilation/transpilation of a library I wrote using gulp, typescript, and babel.  The problem I'm having lies in the inclusion of external libraries.  My project aims to use MathJS, RequireJS, RXJS, and JQuery.

During compilation, I get the following errors:
[Compilation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSXgi.png)

Upon finishing the compilation/transpilation, I then reference my entry point (/services/bid-manager.service.js) and when I try to load the file, I get the following error:
[Runtime (Chrome conosole) errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04KWO.png)

My current setup looks like so:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "bid-manager-service",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Service for calculating bids for PVBid",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "private",
    "pvbid",
    "bid",
    "manager"
  ],
  "author": "Michael J. Miller",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "mathjs": "^3.6.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

var tsProject = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject()))
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('release'));
});
```

And the first couple lines to my entrypoint, where I'm getting the error:

**Typescript:**

```
import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';
import { Observable }   from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

**Transpiled Javascript:**

```
"use strict";

var AsyncSubject_1 = require('rxjs/AsyncSubject');
var bid_update_service_1 = require('./bid-update.service');
var bid_factory_1 = require('../factories/bid.factory');
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

This error is one that frustrated me when integrating typescript to my project for the first time, but it is due to you not including the correct typings (typing definition files file.d.ts) for TS.

To explain TS is a superset of JS, because it is a superset it requires you to define the packages that allow TS to 'learn' about the packages you are using to create typescript compile time errors. For example this is a very basic example; if you have something that is `let foo: string` and you pass in a number instead `foo = 1`, you would get an error when gulp tries to compile the TS.  The error you would be receiving at compile time is what the typing definition file is used for to give 'typings' to a non typed JS file.

**Note**: Even though you are receiving those errors the file should be compiling to JS and as long as you have no errors your files should work with your build. Although if you continue using ts with the typing errors it might be better to just use JS

---

If you have not done this yet you should follow and familiarize yourself with the [Typings Doc](https://github.com/typings/typings). Install typings globally on your computer and then define the typings you need by looking for the one you need.

For example you would install with the following:

```
# Install typings library using npm    
npm install typings -g 

# Search the typings repositories for the one you want
# rxjs = your module 
typings search rxjs

# Choose from the ones that are available and replace dt~mocha below
# dt~ = the source usually either dt or npm 
typings install dt~rxjs--global --save
```

The following should have created a typings.json and typings folder with the information/files you downloaded on first install.

One thing I will note about typing definition files is that not all js libraries are available. Therefore you will either need:

1. Completely rewrite the JS file you want to TS
2. Wait until your desired package is released by someone else
3. If you are feeling adventurous contribute to the typings community by creating a typings definition file (d.ts) for the module you need, i'm sure many would appreciate it if it is not yet available.